# Maximum level of sub categories for each parent category in magento

Tags: magento, categories

How to get the last level of sub-category for each parent category?

- iphone

  - 4s

    - 16gb
  - 5s

    - 32gb
    - white
    - black
- ipad

  - mini

    - 16gb
  - air
  - retina

    - 32gb

      - white
      - black

I just want the names of final sub categories of each parent categories (i.e) 16gb,air,white,black...

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the logic how you can achieve it. Hope it will help.

For achieving this we need to go through each category till we get the end of category nodes. Recursively each category subcategories will be get the at each level same them with a separate array like this [1] => Category1, Category2 and so on. At the end you will be having array like [0] => category1, category2 [1]=> category1, category2 ....

Now just get the last array key elements and that is your final categories array.

Thanks,
Mohit

Comment: Thank you,but i don't want to have recursives.is there any way to get the count of levels for each parent category in magento.